# How to avoid SELECT COUNT in a SELECT statement for partial percentages

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I want to calculate the partial percentage for each SiteName here but I would
need to calculate the aggregate count of my rows.

The following query works but is there a way to do this without using the SELECT
within the SELECT statement or declaring a variable for this? I only have read access so
I can't declare variables.

```
SELECT

ServiceSiteName   
, COUNT(*)                                  AS [Alarms Resolved]
-- How can I avoid this.
, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [C1Datastore].[dbo].[Fct_AlertCRM_Incident] 
    WHERE Conditions A, B, C)       AS [Total Count]
    
, COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [C1Datastore].[dbo].[Fct_AlertCRM_Incident] 
    WHERE Conditions A, B, C)       AS [% Count]

FROM TableX
WHERE Conditions A, B, C

GROUP BY 
ServiceSiteName

ORDER BY [Alarms Resolved]  DESC
```

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use SUM(COUNT()) OVER (PARTITION BY) and this is much shorter.

```
SELECT

ServiceSiteName   
, COUNT(*)                                  AS [Alarms Resolved]

    
-- Use this 
, SUM(COUNT(1)) OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceSiteName)     AS [TOTAL]
, COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(1)) OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceSiteName)         AS [% Count]


FROM TableX
WHERE Conditions A, B, C

GROUP BY 
ServiceSiteName

ORDER BY [Alarms Resolved]  DESC
```